# Train station optimization

Tags: probability, optimization, expected-value

> I found the following discussion in the comments section of the blog below started by the commenter "gowers"
>
> Blog: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/12/09/an-airport-inspired-puzzle/
>
> The problem can be stated as:
>
> Suppose the next train to your destination leaves at 12 pm, however, when leaving your house you are completely unaware of when the next train leaves. All you know, as of 11am, is that a train will leave the station sometime in the next hour. What is the average time saved by mixing in intervals of running and walking while going to the station as opposed to just walking the entire way?

**My solution would be:**

Suppose the train leaves at 12pm. Suppose your trip to the station takes $x$ minutes if you walk and $x - y$ minutes if you mix walking and running. Then take $n$ = $60$ to be the number of minutes in an hour and $D$ the length of intervals between 12pm train and the next train after it. Supposing we run an experiment and leave from each minute around the clock between 11pm and 12pm we would have the average time saved as:

$$\frac{D(y)}{60}$$

The $D(y)$ comes from: There are $60$ possible minutes we can leave from. We compute for each minute in the hour, how much of a gain walking/running as opposed to only walking to gives us in our total time to destination. The only possible minutes where walking can fail to reach the 12pm train are if we leave after 12pm - $x$ minutes. Since running decreases the time to the station by $y$ minutes, we have $y$ cases (each case being a minute on the clock) where running is superior to walking. In each of these cases, we gain $D$ amount of time compared to if we had chosen to walk. Hence we gain $D(y)$ in terms of total gained time over walking. Dividing this over the total number of minutes sampled we have $\frac{D(y)}{60}$. Note that D(y) is D $\cdot$ y, not a function.

If we suppose the person could leave their house not at every minute but every second or some smaller unit of time then this would not change the above as both the numerator and denominator would change by the same factor when considering units saved and total units in an hour.

Edit: It appears Gowers is referring to expected value, not average as I compute it.

However, "Gowers" answers:

"since the average time you save is equal to the time you save on that leg of it by running rather than walking."

Thanks!

Comment: (btw, gowers is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timothy_Gowers)

Comment: ahhhhhhh alrighty then

Answer (score 1):

Here I think is a translation into mathematical terms of what T. Gowers posted. I think the difference from your approach is to recognize the problem as a probabilistic one: since you don't know the time the train leaves, from your point of view it's random (his 'average' is a probabilistic expectation).

Let $M$ be a uniformly random integer between 0 and 60, and say that there's a train out there which leaves $M$ minutes past every hour. You don't know $M$, and you're leaving to head to the train. Let's say that it takes $0<x<60$ minutes to walk to the station and that you save $0<y<x$ minutes by running. Let's fix a duration for the train trip, call it $D$ (this can be any amount of time, but let's express it in minutes). Finally, let's say that you leave your house at 11:00.

Now, let's compute some probabilities. The probability that you miss the 11:$M$ train without running is the same as the probability that $M\leq x$, and since $M$ was uniformly distributed

\begin{align*}
P(\text{miss train without running})&=\frac{x}{60}\\\\
P(\text{make train without running})&=1-\frac{x}{60}.
\end{align*}

Similarly,

\begin{align*}
P(\text{miss train with running})&=\frac{x-y}{60}\\\\
P(\text{make train with running})&=1-\frac{x-y}{60}.
\end{align*}

Now that we have probabilities, we can compute expectations. We leave the house at 11:00, and either make the 11:$M$ train or miss it and take the 12:$M$ train, and then get there $D$ minutes after we get on the train. If we make the 11:$M$ train, then our total trip duration is $D+M$ minutes. If we make the 12:$M$ train, our trip duration is $D+M+60$ minutes (we lost an hour from missing the train and catching the next one).

So, if we don't run, our expected trip duration is:

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[\text{trip duration without running}]&=\frac{x}{60}\cdot(D+M+60) + \left(1-\frac{x}{60}\right)\cdot(D+M)\\\\
&=D+M + x.
\end{align*}

If we do run,

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[\text{trip duration with running}]&=\frac{x-y}{60}\cdot(D+M+60) + \left(1-\frac{x-y}{60}\right)\cdot(D+M)\\\\
&=D+M+x-y.
\end{align*}

We can see that running saves $y$ minutes on average. (Hopefully this gives some insight into why trip duration does not matter. It's easy to extend this into train intervals other than 1 hour as long as $0<y<x<$ interval. If $x$ is larger than the interval, the answer can change, but let's not worry about that here.)

Comment: Ahh thank you very much! I believe the assumption that x is less than the interval would be consistent with Gowers problem as he described running from the steps to the platform suggesting the steps are quite close to the platform. How would the expected value here relate to what I computed?

Comment: I had some trouble following your computation -- in particular, I was not sure why $T$ and $y$ were multiplied, or how this was determined to be the average. I'd be happy to look again if you can post some more steps in your computation.

Comment: ahh so my solution was wrong. It really isnt a function of the length of the trip, the total amount saved would be the interval to the next train. Then my numerator would be y*1 as I save 1 hour for every time I decide to run instead of walk, and it would only be time saved in y cases. So in this case we have y/60 = average amount saved, where we assume over some long time period I am equally likely to leave my house at every minute in the hour.

Comment: I think the time saved should still be $y$ if your leaving time is random (choice of 11:00 was arbitrary here, and if you put in a variable for the leaving time, it would just get integrated out -- you should have a sum over leaving times in your computation somewhere)

Comment: So i re wrote my post as I'm thinking of it now, I am looking at it as more of an experiment testing each minute from 0 to 60 and computing the average time saved after compiling 60 results

Comment: Still not sure where the $Dy$ comes from. I would personally suggest that you consider a detailed derivation involving probabilities if you want to make a convincing argument. You could for instance set up the leaving time to be a uniform random variable, and see how that gets incorporated into the derivation that I presented (the expected time saved will still be $y$, but I think I should leave this as an exercise).

Comment: ok, I made some edits to hopefully clear up what I am writing. Does that help?

Comment: I think it is still incorrect. The problem comes in the line where you divide by 60 -- it's not clear that in $y/60$ cases you save $D$ minutes -- actually, in $y/D$ cases you save that time, but of course this needs proof. To make a convincing demonstration, like I said above, please start from your assumptions and make a proof, don't just state your answer and write some lines justifying it after.

Comment: (In my answer, you can just replace the number of minutes in an "hour" with some number other than 60 to generalize to arbitrary intervals between trains.)

Comment: I am only taking a sampling of each "minute mark" around the clock from 11am to 12pm, so my sample has size 60. At each minute I ask the question of whether running saves me time over walking. In some cases there is 0 time saved, in other cases there is a time amount of $D$ saved -- these are the only two options. I note the result for each minute mark on the clock, sum the total amount saved and divide by 60 -- that is my average. In $\frac{y}{60}$ cases I will save time as I can leave later and still make the 12pm train.

Comment: Why are there exactly $y$ minutes out of each 60 where you save time? That's where the mistake is.

Comment: Why do you believe in $y/D$ cases you save $D$ minutes?

Comment: Let's look at an example. Say the train leaves every 10 minues, at 11:00, 11:10, etc. Say $y=2$ minutes and $x=5$ minutes so that $x-y=3$ minutes is the time to get there if you run. You save time by running if you leave at 11:06, 11:07, 11:16, 11:17, ..., 11:56, 11:57, or in other words 2 out of every 10 minutes. (not 2 out of 60 minutes). (This example can easily be turned into a proof that it's y/D)

Comment: (Another way to see that it should not be $y/60$ -- why should the answer to this question depend on the length of an hour? Is it really true that if hours had 100 minutes in them instead of 60, running to the train would save less time?)

Comment: In the problem I stated we are leaving our house sometime in the 11th hour for the 12pm train. It is fixed the train leaves at 12pm. The denominator is 60 as we are only computing the average for this 1 scenario of trying to catch the 12pm train given you only know the train will arrive sometime in the next hour. Of course, my solution does not generalize at all, for if the train left at 11:30 it would be wrong. But it only seeks to compute an average for a fixed train departure of 12pm. I feel I answered my question, but not Gowers as I mistranslated his problem at the top of the post.